# I didn't figure out how the result in part (i) can help in (ii). Anyone has any idea??

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

The determinant turns out to be -3 in part (i)
How can this help in showing that the 4 vectors in the end are linearly independent?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think about the rank of the original matrix, and the rank of the $7\times 4$ matrix you could put together in part ii.

Answer (score 0):

if the determinant is non zero, then the four column vectors of that matrix is linearly independent. now, if you tack three more numbers at the end to make seven component vectors they are still linearly independent. so the new set of four vectors is linearly independent.